# npm is not using cache

Tags: node.js, caching, jenkins

Caveat, I am running `npm install` from within a Docker container that is being used as a Jenkins build slave but I have established that the npm cache is not corrupted and is being stored in a volume persisted across container runs and rms, you can see [that proof here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/jenkins-docker-build-slave-npm-cache-not-working)

When I run `npm cache ls` many packages from my package.config are listed:
[image]

And yet, every time I run `npm install` or `npm --skip-installed --cache-min 9999999 install` every single package is installed.

- The environment is is a Centos7 docker container
- node --version 6.11.4
- npm --version 3.10.10

When I run `npm install` twice on my localhost Windows 10 machine, same node version and npm version, the cache is clearly used the second time `npm install` is ran:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cache the RUN npm install instruction when docker build a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774714/how-to-cache-the-run-npm-install-instruction-when-docker-build-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issues of caching NPM packages in a Docker container here:
https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/2936/4790